# How to run a timer?

Tags: java

I want to run a timer which says time is expired after 30 seconds,how can do so? 
Some task to be run only for some seconds then showing expired, how can i do so?

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) from the `java.util.concurrent` package, which has a richer API than other `Timer` implementations within the JDK.

```
// Create timer service with a single thread.
ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// Schedule a one-off task to run in 10 seconds time.
// It is also possible to schedule a repeating task.
timer.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
  public Void call() {
    System.err.println("Expired!");

    // Return a value here.  If we know we don't require a return value
    // we could submit a Runnable instead of a Callable to the service.
    return null;
  }
}, 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: i am not understanding the above example,i have code that gets expired in 30 seconds so i want to run a timer and show a message after 30 saying expired

Comment: You new to create a class implementing either the Runnable or Callable interface.  This represents the "unit of work" that you send to the ScheduledExecutorService (i.e. timer), which the service will then run at some point in the future (10 seconds in the above example).  In my example I've used an anonymous inner class to implement Callable, but there's no reason you couldn't define a named class; e.g. public class DoExpire implements Callable<Void> { ... }, and then submit it to the service by calling timer.schedule(new DoExpire(), 10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The actionPerformed method is called after 30 sec

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new JFrame().setVisible( true );
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println( "expired" );
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer( 30000, actionListener );
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for javax.swing.Timer in an economical Swing app; -0.01 for neglecting to build on the EDT. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).